# Presenting a View controller only in the DetailViewController of UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am working with UISplitViewController, and I want to present a VC from the detail view controller of the splitViewController. I do it like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

also tried this from master VC.

```
[self.detailVC presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

It comes for the full screen I mean it is like presenting from the UISplitViewController itself. I tried changing the modal presentation styles even though I got the same results.

**What I want is the VC that is presented should be presented within the bounds of the DetailVC and it can be of DetailVC's entire frame, but not come anywhere near to the MasterVC.**

For now I am using UIView Animation to achieve this, any ideas on how to do this just by presenting?

Comment: do you have answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 6:

In the storyboard, select the present modally segue, and go to the Identity Inspector, and choose Current Context for the Presentation option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your detail view controller should be inside a navigation controller, then you push your additional view controller into the navigation controller instead of modally.

Comment: I don't want to push I want to present the VC.

Comment: Presenting, even if you force the frame, will at least dim the master view and prevent interaction. Is that your intention?